# Array outside while doesn't function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Sorry for the beginner question. 
I'm searching about an hour, but I can't understand why my $row outside from the second while doesn't function... The name variable run just the $row var doesn't function...

```
$i = 0;
while($i < 8)
{
    $str = "SELECT * FROM `$name[$i]`";
    $result = mysql_query($str, $connessione);
    $l = mysql_num_rows($result);

    while($l > 1)
    {
        $strs = "SELECT * FROM `$name[$i]` WHERE `Livello` = '$l'";
        $results = mysql_query($strs, $connessione);
        $row[$i][$l] = mysql_fetch_array($results);

            if I put here the echo I can view the mysql variable 
            echo $row[$i][$l]['var'];

        $l--;
    }
        if I put here echo $row[$i][$l]['var']; he send me the error " Undefined offset"
    $i++;
}
```

Hope you can help me...

Comment: What does "doesn't function" mean?!

Comment: what is if `mysql_num_rows($result)` return 1, then `$l > 1` is false.

Comment: If `$l` is `0` to begin with, the `$row` variable will not be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the place where you put:

```
echo $row[$i][$l]['var'];
```

`$l` value is 0 and you set $row values for `$l` from 1 to `mysql_num_rows($result)`

if you put there:

```
echo $row[$i][1]['var'];
```

it should work fine assuming `mysql_num_rows($result)` was more than 1 element.

Probably your code should look like this:

```
$i = 0;
while($i < 8)
{
    $str = "SELECT * FROM `$name[$i]`";
    $result = mysql_query($str, $connessione);
    $l = mysql_num_rows($result);

    while($l > 0) // changed 1 to 0
    {
        $strs = "SELECT * FROM `$name[$i]` WHERE `Livello` = '$l'";
        $results = mysql_query($strs, $connessione);
        $row[$i][$l] = mysql_fetch_array($results);

            if i put here the echo i can view the mysql variable 
            echo $row[$i][$l]['var'];

        $l--;
    }

    // added extra loop to display array values
    $whileIndex = 0;
    while (true) {
      if (!isset($row[$i][$whileIndex]['var']) {
         break;
      }
      echo $row[$i][$whileIndex]['var']; // should work
      ++$whileIndex;
    }


    $i++;
}
```

Comment: in the first echo i can view the code is in the second the problem... if i put your code i got the same problem

Comment: I've added possible solution to my answer

Answer (score 0):

When you try to use `echo`, `$i = 8` and `$l = 1`. These keys doesn´t exists in your array.

Comment: i want the variable for the $i between 0 and 7 (8 vars) and for $l between 1 and mysql num rows (different var)

Comment: You have to use `echo` in second loop, not behind.